# Get Prior Value using Oracle SQL in effective dated table

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I get prior value in an effective dated table with criteria?

For example, I want to get all employees who moved out of Florida (FL) state

Here is the table data:

| Emplid | Effdt | State |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01-JAN-2022 | FL |
| 1 | 05-JAN-2022 | FL |
| 1 | 01-JAN-2023 | OH |
| 2 | 01-JAN-2021 | NY |
| 2 | 01-JAN-2022 | CA |
| 3 | 01-JAN-2019 | FL |
| 3 | 01-JAN-2023 | TX |

Expected Results:

| Emplid | Effdt | State |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 05-JAN-2022 | FL |
| 1 | 01-JAN-2023 | OH |
| 3 | 01-JAN-2019 | FL |
| 3 | 01-JAN-2023 | TX |

I don't know where to start?

```sql
select * 
from ps_addresses 
where effdt = (
  select max(effdt)
    from (
    select 
      emplid, effdt, STATE, over(order by effdt desc) as prev
      from ps_addresses
    ) x  
    where prev is not null and STATE <> prev
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to get all employees who moved out of Florida (FL) state

If you want to get the pair of rows when the employee started in Florida and then moved, in the next row, to Florida then, from Oracle 12, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM   ps_addresses 
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  PARTITION BY emplid
  ORDER     BY effdt
  ALL ROWS PER MATCH
  PATTERN (fl not_fl)
  DEFINE
    fl     AS state = 'FL',
    not_fl AS state != 'FL'
);
```

Or, you can use the `LAG` and `LEAD` analytic functions:

```sql
SELECT emplid,
       effdt,
       state
FROM   (
  SELECT p.*,
         LAG(state) OVER (PARTITION BY emplid ORDER BY effdt) AS prev_state,
         LEAD(state) OVER (PARTITION BY emplid ORDER BY effdt) AS next_state
  FROM   ps_addresses p
)
WHERE  ( state = 'FL' AND next_state != 'FL' )
OR     ( state != 'FL' AND prev_state = 'FL' );
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE ps_addresses (Emplid, Effdt, State) AS
SELECT 1, DATE '2022-01-01', 'FL' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2022-01-05', 'FL' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2023-01-01', 'OH' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2021-01-01', 'NY' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2022-01-01', 'CA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, DATE '2019-01-01', 'FL' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, DATE '2023-01-01', 'TX' FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

| EMPLID | EFFDT | STATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-05 00:00:00 | FL |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | OH |
| 3 | 2019-01-01 00:00:00 | FL |
| 3 | 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | TX |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/7x0oMnzr)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, this worked!